# Unable to start blueprint container for bundle abc, org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to deploy my application in fuse server but it gives me an error "Unable to start blueprint container for bundle abc, 
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.NullPointerException". I have camel-core and camel-blueprint jars but still it gives me the error. Not sure what it refers. Please can anyone help on this?

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        id="abc" threadNamePattern="#camelId#-#longName#-#counter#">

        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="blueprint:sql.prop.id" />


        <route id="logMessageRoute" startupOrder="5">
            <from uri="direct:logMessage" />
            <camel:setProperty propertyName="originalMap">
                <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
            </camel:setProperty>
            <to uri="direct:insertMessage" />
            <log message="INSERT COMPLETED" loggingLevel="INFO" />
            <onException>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <camel:log message="EXCEPTION IN direct:Message ROUTE " />
            </onException>
        </route>

        <camel:route id="insertLogRoute" startupOrder="4">
            <camel:from uri="direct:insertMessage" />
<!--            <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />  -->
            <recipientList delimiter="~" id="insertLogMessageRecipientId">
                <simple>sql:{{insertQuery}}</simple>
            </recipientList>
            <onException>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <camel:log message="EXCEPTION IN direct:insertLogMessage ROUTE "
                    loggingLevel="INFO" />
                <!-- <camel:to uri="direct:generateCSV" /> -->
            </onException>
        </camel:route>


    </camelContext>
    </blueprint>```


Stack trace: 
```
2019-11-17 19:22:11,239 | ERROR | pool-15-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.5 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle abc,
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.ValueRecipe.internalCreate(ValueRecipe.java:56)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:955)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:929)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:910)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:844)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:247)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:688)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:383)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:270)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.doInstallFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:546)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.4.0.redhat-621166]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:432)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.4.0.redhat-621166]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434)[28:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt:1.9.3.redhat_3]
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:804)[28:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt:1.9.3.redhat_3]
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:617)[28:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt:1.9.3.redhat_3]
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553)[28:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt:1.9.3.redhat_3]
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705)[28:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt:1.9.3.redhat_3]
        at org.apache.karaf.jaas.jasypt.handler.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholder.getProperty(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholder.java:38)[29:org.apache.karaf.jaas.jasypt:2.4.0.redhat-621166]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.retrieveValue(AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.java:430)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.processString(AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.java:437)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.AbstractPropertyPlaceholder$LateBindingValueMetadata.getStringValue(AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.java:471)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.AbstractPropertyPlaceholder$LateBindingValueMetadata.getStringValue(AbstractPropertyPlaceholder.java:469)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.ValueRecipe.internalCreate(ValueRecipe.java:54)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.5]
        ... 35 more ```
````

Comment: The stacktrace indicate its something to do with encrypted property placeholders where camel-jasypt triggers a NPE error. Maybe that can help you. Take a look in your bundle if you do anything with encrypted values.